# How to customize Ionic Input Placehoder

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I m setting up login page using ionic. I want to change the color of placeholder inside Ion-input. How to achieve that using CSS

I tried

```
.text-input::-moz-placeholder
{
   color: white;
}

.text-input:-ms-input-placeholder 
{
   color: white;
}

 .text-input::-webkit-input-placeholder 
 {
   text-indent: 0;
   color: white;
 }
```

But it not working

Answer (score 0):

Go to your variables.scss and add this following code at the end :

```
*::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: white;
}
*:-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 4-18 */
    color: $roadmate-header-icon;
}
*::-moz-placeholder {
    /* FF 19+ */
    color: white;
}
*:-ms-input-placeholder {
    /* IE 10+ */
    color: white;
}
```

This will affect all inputs in your app regardless of what class you apply.
In your code you were targeting only inputs that have a class called **text-input** applied to it

Answer (score 0):

```
ion-input
{
        --placeholder-color:#fff;
         --color: #fff;
}
```

Using above code you can change placeholder color and text color of input field in Ionic. 
for more 
https://beta.ionicframework.com/docs/api/input